# Change Color SetEnabled

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextfield, uimanager

My question is this:
Default change the color to give a JTextField setEnabled (false) for example is black and proven with UIManager results but have not had any suggestions.

Greetings.

Comment: Please rephrase your question..I'm having difficulty understanding you.

Comment: Have you tried using `setDisabledTextColor`?

Comment: I want to change default color when I put my JTextField.setEnable (false) on the other color.

Comment: What default color? foreground or background?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/403/capturadepantalla201205um.png/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change disabled background color try this:

```
UIManager.put("TextField.disabledBackground", Color.GRAY);
```

You can change disabled text color using [setDisabledTextColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setDisabledTextColor%28java.awt.Color%29), i.e.:

```
textField.setDisabledTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

***EDIT: include SSCCE***

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestDisabledTextField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("TextField.disabledBackground", Color.YELLOW);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Disabled text field", 15);
        textField.setEnabled(false);
        textField.setDisabledTextColor(Color.RED);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(textField);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `UIManager` line doesn't work for me.  When I inspect the output of `UIManager.getDefaults()` I don't see `TextField.disabledBackground` which makes me think that it's not really an option.

Comment: Actually, I think the 'UIManager' key should be `TextField.inactiveBackground`.

Comment: My apologies.  I think I incorrectly extrapolated when I made my comments.  I came across this question really trying to set the disabled foreground with UIManager.  Using your SSCCE above, if I want to set the disabled foreground using UIManager, I have to use `TextField.inactiveForeground` as `TextField.disabledForeground` seems to have no effect.  I guess I just assumed that disabled => inactive for both background and foreground.  But I do concede that your example works.